# Error : The manifest file does not exist

Tags: python, crosswalk

Estou tendo essse erro quando compilo o meu app crosswalk com o comando:

`>>> python make_apk.py`

Após esse comando passo também os valores como `--package`, `--manifest`. Porém, o manifest não funciona. Acho que deve ser um erro de pastas em que o compilador não encontra o meu app.

O que pode ser? Grato desde já.

Comment: No erro exibe em qual caminho o arquivo manifest.xml está sendo procurado? O arquivo exite no local que deveria estar?

Comment: Verifiquei se o nome do arquivo esta correto e se o mesmo esta na correta .